# LM358 as a voltage follower only reaches 1.5 V of supply voltage

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, buffer

[image]

I am using an LM358 as a voltage follower, giving it a supply voltage of 6 volts and input voltage of 5V

At the output I am getting 4.5V.  By applying different configurations of input voltage and supply voltage I observed that there should a difference of 1.5V between supply voltage (Vcc) and input voltage.(IN+.) I am not able to find the reason behind it.

Comment: The explanation is in the datasheet.

Comment: The full explanation is in the application note [Design Guidelines for Devices with LM324/LM358 Cores](https://www.ti.com/lit/pdf/sloa277).

Comment: BJT style cannot go to both rails but some can saturate near Vee, while CMOS can,

Comment: thanks @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75

Comment: You need to do much more reading on good design reviews before you can learn to design. Much faster than trial and fail

Comment: thanks for your suggestion @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75. I would read good design reviews for increasing my knowledge .

Comment: Gloss over this to get  that reliable products come from analyzing the problems defining how to measure it and design a solution for it in the environmental and functional aspects then the details electronic terms ,, a bit over the top but you get the idea why I say GOOD specs before you start a design.

Comment: https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a234709.pdf

Comment: This requires to read every application design book too

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 is link is not working can tell me the the website from where i can download this book

Comment: Its big, be patient. Unless your IP zone is blocked

Answer (score 3):

This is to be expected from [the LM358.](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/lm358-n)

The datasheet says that the output range is from 0V to V+ minus 1.5V.

This is the relevant section of the datasheet:

[image]

Comment: thanks for help@JRE

Comment: like is there a op amp in which supply voltage can be equal to input voltage?

Comment: There are many.  Search for "rail to rail" opamps.

Answer (score 2):

The input voltage range is 1.5 V (2V) lower than the positive supply voltage.

[image: lm]

Comment: thanks for help@csabahu

Answer (score 1):

The LM358 is unable to raise it's output closer to the positive supply than about 1.5 volts and that appears to be what you are seeing. Strictly speaking and going by the data sheet the upper limit is Vcc minus 2 volts so, a real LM358 might be able to raise the output to 4 volts.

It's the same with the input pins of the LM358 - they cannot be relied upon to work when they get within 2 volts of the upper supply rail.

[image]

Purple is output and red is input. The output spec is for a positive rail of 30 volts hence, the 28 volt typical value is Vcc minus 2 volts.

Comment: thanks for help@andy aka

Comment: we should probably make this the reference/duplicate Q&A for "help! my opamp doesn't reach supply rails" questions.